# Systemd bug? Stdout not tagged as belonging to unit when non-root User= specified

Tags: systemd

*(Edit: reworked question to avoid initial confusion with syslog)*

A bit of bizarro systemd behaviour, which I'd like to either confirm as a bug, documentation failure or PEBCAK.

Consider a very simple unit that runs as root:

```
# cat > /etc/systemd/system/testecho.service <<EOF
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo 'Hello world'
User=root
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

With `User=root` (or `User` unspecified) stdout goes to the journal tagged as the unit's, as one would expect:

```
# journalctl -u testecho -f &
# systemctl start testecho
Jan 21 19:37:33 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com systemd[1]: Starting testecho.service...
Jan 21 19:37:33 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com echo[13479]: Hello world
Jan 21 19:37:33 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com systemd[1]: Started testecho.service.
```

However when a service is run as any non-root user, e.g. `nobody`, stdout is *not* tagged as the unit's, and won't appear if you run `journalctl` with `-u`:

```
# cat > /etc/systemd/system/testecho.service <<EOF
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo 'Hello world'
User=nobody
EOF
# systemctl daemon-reload
# journalctl -u testecho -f &
# systemctl start testecho
Jan 21 19:38:56 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com systemd[1]: Starting testecho.service...
Jan 21 19:38:56 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com systemd[1]: Started testecho.service.
```

In fact stdout is going to the journal, but with no _SYSTEMD_UNIT tag. Stdout can be seen by leaving off the `-u testunit`:

```
# journalctl -f &
systemctl start testecho
# systemctl start testecho
Jan 21 19:42:04 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com systemd[1]: Starting testecho.service...
Jan 21 19:42:04 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com echo[13719]: Hello world
Jan 21 19:42:04 atlassian-app01.phx7.llnw.com systemd[1]: Started testecho.service.
```

This can also be confirmed by running `journalctl -o json-pretty -f`. When `User=` is non-root, there's no `"_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "testecho.service"` field.

The docs on [StandardOutput=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) say nothing of magical variance based on `User`, and nor do the docs for [User=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=). All they say is that `StandardOutput` inherits `DefaultStandardOutput`, and defaults to `journal`.

Am I missing something? I note that my service's stdout is always goes to syslog, regardless of `User`

I've seen this on systemd 229 and 231 running on Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: i'd suspect some permissions blocking `nobody` from writing into the journal.  do you get the same issue with a real user?  ... with a real user in the `systemd-journal` group (or similar)?

Comment: Do you get the same result with `logger` and `systemd-cat`?

Comment: @quixotic, it happens with any non-root user, in systemd-journal group or not.

Comment: An update: I've found that stdout *is* actually logged to the journal, but when `User=nobody` (or any non-root user) is specified, the message isn't tagged as belonging to the unit (`testecho` in the example). So the message can be seen with `journalctl -f` but not `journalctl -u testecho -f`. The lack of tag can be seen by running `journalctl -o json-pretty` - with `User=root` or `User=` omitted, one gets a `"_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "testecho.service"` tag, but no tag with `User=nobody`. Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: nice additional info. first thought: bug. second thought: `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` designation only used for system services?  if you omit the `User=` declaration and run the service as your normal user (`systemd --user`) does it have the same effect?

Comment: related (similar issue, older version): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109490/where-is-why-is-there-no-log-for-normal-user-systemd-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a known issue that there are presently not plans to fix. See:

- [journald entries that should have _SYSTEMD_UNIT are /sometimes/ missing _SYSTEMD_UNIT #1347](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1347)

Comment: Confirmed, thanks! If I change `ExecStart=/bin/echo 'Hello world'` to `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/echo 'Hello world'; sleep 0.1"`, I get tagged output even with `User=nobody`.